# Excel - Move rows containing an empty cell to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first attempt at VBA, so I apologize for my ignorance.  The situation is as follows:  I have a spreadsheet that consists of 4 columns and 629 rows.  When I am trying to do is iterate through the 4 cells in each row and check for a blank cell.  If there is a row that contains a blank cell, I want to cut it from Sheet1 and paste it into the first available row in Sheet2.

(Ideally the number of columns AND the number of rows is dynamic based on each spreadsheet, but I have no idea how to iterate through rows and columns dynamically)

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' Move lines containing empty cells to sheet 2
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'


Dim Continue As Boolean
Dim FirstRow As Long
Dim CurrentRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim EmptySheetCount As Long


Dim Counter As Integer


'Initialize Variables

LContinue = True
FirstRow = 2
CurrentRow = FirstRow
LastRow = 629
EmptySheetCount = 1

'Sheets(Sheet1).Select

'Iterate through cells in each row until an empty one is found
While (CurrentRow <= LastRow)

    For Counter = 1 To 4

        If Sheet1.Cells(CurrentRow, Counter).Value = "" Then

            Sheet1.Cells(CurrentRow).EntireRow.Cut Sheet2.Cells(EmptySheetCount, "A")
            EmptySheetCount = EmptySheetCount + 1
            Counter = 1
            CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
            GoTo BREAK

        Else

            Counter = Counter + 1

        End If

        Counter = 1
BREAK:
    Next

Wend
End Sub
```

When I run it, I typically get an error around the Sheet1.Cells(CurrentRow, Counter).Value = "" area, so I know I'm referencing sheets incorrectly.  I've tried Sheets(Sheet1), Worksheets("Sheet1") and nothing seems to be working.  When I do change to Worksheets("Sheet1"), however, it runs and just freezes Excel.

I know I'm doing multiple things wrong, I just know way too little to know what.

Thanks a lot in advance. And sorry for the crap formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code so rather than go through them individually here is a basic looping version that does what you're after.

```
Sub moveData()

    Dim wksData As Worksheet
    Dim wksDestination As Worksheet

    Dim lastColumn As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    Dim destinationRow As Integer

    Set wksData = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wksDestination = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    destinationRow = 1

    lastColumn = wksData.Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastRow = wksData.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1    'go 'up' the worksheet to handle 'deletes'
        For j = 1 To lastColumn
            If wksData.Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then      'check for a blank cell in the current row
                'if there is a blank, cut the row
                wksData.Activate
                wksData.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, lastColumn)).Cut

                wksDestination.Activate
                wksDestination.Range(Cells(destinationRow, 1), Cells(destinationRow, lastColumn)).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste

                'If required this code will delete the 'cut' row
                wksData.Rows(i).Delete shift:=xlUp

                'increment the output row
                destinationRow = destinationRow + 1

                Exit For     'no need to carry on with this loop as a blank was already found
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    set wksData = Nothing
    set wksDestination = Nothing

End Sub
```

There are other ways that will achieve the same outcome but this should give you and idea of how to use `loops`, `sheets`, `ranges`, etc.

The `lastColumn` and `lastRow` variables will find the the last column/row of data in the given columns/rows (i.e, in my code it finds the last column of data in row `1`, and the last row of data in column `A`).

Also, you should get into the habit of debugging and stepping through code to identify errors and see exactly what each line is doing (this will also help you learn too).

Comment: That's excellent, tospig, it works beautifully.  I've been working on this for a couple of hours and you nailed it within a few minutes.  debugging and stepping through the code is definitely a good call.  I understand most of what you've done, with a few exceptions. The string in the following: wksData.Range("XFD1"), I assume this is something specific to Excel?  The same with the string in the next line?

Comment: @coreytrevor `XFD` is the last column in an Excel sheet (version 2007). `1048576` is the last row.  The `End(xlup)` is saying, go to the last row (1048576), then go `up` the sheet until you find some data. The row with this data in is then the `lastRow`.

Comment: Awesome, you've been incredibly helpful.  Thank you again for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this of use.
It uses an array variable to store the values of the cells in the row to be moved.  It does not use cut and paste, so only transfer the data values, and the code does not require activation of the required sheets.
The destination rows are in the same order as the rows on the original sheet.
The method used to find the last cell used in the row and column is more elegant than other answers given.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test_moveData()

    Dim wksData As Worksheet
    Dim wksDestination As Worksheet

    Set wksData = shtSheet1         ' Use the Codename "shtSheet1" for the worksheet. ie the value of the sheet property that is displayed as "(Name)"
    Set wksDestination = shtSheet2

    moveData wksData, wksDestination

End Sub
Public Sub moveData(wksData As Worksheet, wksDestination As Worksheet)

    Dim ilastColumn As Integer
    Dim ilastRow As Integer
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iColumn As Long
    Dim iDestinationRowNumber As Integer

    Dim MyArray() As Variant
    Dim rngRowsToDelete As Range


    iDestinationRowNumber = 1

    ilastColumn = wksData.Cells(1, wksData.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ilastRow = wksData.Cells(wksData.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ReDim MyArray(1, ilastColumn)
    Set rngRowsToDelete = Nothing

    For iRow = 1 To ilastRow Step 1     'No need to go 'up' the worksheet to handle 'deletes'

        For iColumn = 1 To ilastColumn

            If wksData.Cells(iRow, iColumn).Value = "" Then        'check for a blank cell in the current row

                MyArray = wksData.Range(wksData.Cells(iRow, 1), wksData.Cells(iRow, ilastColumn)).Value

                    wksDestination.Range(wksDestination.Cells(iDestinationRowNumber, 1),
                     wksDestination.Cells(iDestinationRowNumber, ilastColumn) _ 
                                        ).Value = MyArray

                'Store the rows to be deleted
                If rngRowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngRowsToDelete = wksData.Rows(iRow)
                Else
                    Set rngRowsToDelete = Union(rngRowsToDelete, wksData.Rows(iRow))
                End If

                'increment the output row
                iDestinationRowNumber = iDestinationRowNumber + 1

                Exit For     'no need to carry on with this loop as a blank was already found
            End If

        Next iColumn

    Next iRow

    If Not rngRowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
        rngRowsToDelete.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
    End If
    Set rngRowsToDelete = Nothing

    Set wksData = Nothing
    Set wksDestination = Nothing

End Sub
```

' enjoy

Comment: Arrays are my preferred way of doing this too, but I wanted to show the OP some basic loop notation / concepts. Also, there's an issue with the format of your post on the line `wksDestination.Range(...)`

Comment: Very nice way to do it.  I appreciate the additional information.